# Docker Desktop running pods on WSL cannot resolve host name

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I have the problem noted elsewhere regarding pods running in Docker Desktop via WSL:

> Could not resolve host

In my specific case:

> Could not resolve host: Could not resolve host: login.microsoftonline.com

Reading [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952784/curl-could-not-resolve-host-using-docker-on-wsl-2) [such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561027/kubernetes-pod-cannot-resolve-host) [cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360231/how-to-make-docker-desktop-windows-resolve-the-host-name), here's what I've tried:

- quit Docker Desktop
- terminated WSL using `net stop LxssManager`
- `wsl -l -v` revealed that all distros were in the `Stopped` state
- edited `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\wsl.conf` with the following...

  ```
  [network]
  generateHosts = false
  generateResolvConf = false
  ```
- edited `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` with the following...

  ```
  {  
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"],    << I added this line (other lines were already present).
    "experimental": false,  
    "hosts": [  
      "npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine_windows"  
    ]  
  }
  ```
- edited `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\resolve.conf` with the following...

  ```
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  ```
- restarted WSL using `net start LxssManager`
- restarted Docker Desktop
- waited for all pods to have status `Running`
- opened a pod shell
- `apt update`
- `apt install curl`
- `curl https://login.microsoftonline.com/[OMITTED]/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=[OMITTED]`

And the response:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: login.microsoftonline.com

What else should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are using CoreDNS 1.10.1, rolling back to 1.10.0 has helped me.
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13768